# Heroku Worker Timeout at 3 Minutes

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a Django app on Heroku, and had moved some report processing code to a worker thread, as it can take some time to generate. Everything works fine, except in cases where the report generation will take more than three minutes.

Every time I run it, at the 3 minute mark - give or take a second - I see "LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer", in the logs and the the report processing seems to stop.

It's not dying on the same player, or even in the same method, but always at the same time. Is there a time limit on worker dynos? I've been pouring through the docs the last couple hours and can't find any mention of one.

**Here's a snippet of the log:**

```
Jan 16 10:14:06 myapp app/worker.1:  Generating all individual player reports 
Jan 16 10:14:06 myapp app/worker.1:  Beginning loop of players 
Jan 16 10:14:06 myapp app/worker.1:  Adding report data for player
Jan 16 10:14:06 myapp app/worker.1:  0 
Jan 16 10:14:06 myapp app/worker.1:  In get_player_report_data 
Jan 16 10:14:06 myapp app/worker.1:  In get player positions 
Jan 16 10:14:06 myapp app/worker.1:  In score_data_for_metric_category 
.....
Jan 16 10:17:01 myapp app/worker.1:  In get rank 
Jan 16 10:17:02 myapp app/worker.1:  Finished get rank 
Jan 16 10:17:02 myapp app/worker.1:  In score_data_for_metric_category 
Jan 16 10:17:02 myapp app/worker.1:  In get rank 
Jan 16 10:17:05 myapp app/postgres.27698:  [PINK] [7-1] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
```

**The worker declaration line in my procfile is simply:**

```
worker: python worker.py
```

**The worker.py file is basically taken from the Heroku docs:**

```
import os

import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())

listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')

conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()
```

And I fire up the report generation with:

```
from rq import Queue
from worker import conn

q = Queue(connection=conn)
q.enqueue(generate_all_individual_player_reports, group_id, notes, request.user.email)
```

Comment: I use Django+Heroku+Celery without any issues, so the issue may be with redis

Comment: Of note is that the error message is coming from Postgres - could be a db timeout or bug. Can you provide more detail on what's going on inside the reporting methods? Like where the data is pulled from, what kind of queries, what the data volume looks like, etc.

Comment: The data is pulled from the database, pretty standard Django queries. A lot of the work is on processing the data that gets pulled in. Some queries do have exclude, annotate, and aggregate calls on them. Quick example here:

`return [{'scores': Score.objects.filter(metric=metric, evaluation_event__in=evaluation_events).exclude(
        value=None).annotate(average=Avg('value')).order_by('-player__number'),
        'min_max': Score.objects.filter(metric=metric, evaluation_event__in=evaluation_events).aggregate(Max('value'), Min('value'))}
        for metric in metrics]`

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain the data volume well, but I'll try:
72 players
10-15 metrics per player

And then they get ranked against all other players based on the same metric category.

Very good point about postgres being the one seeming to drop a connection. I'm also going to reach out to Heroku support and see if they can provide assistance, too.